How to Fix 'OpenAPIGenerator is Disabled' Error in Xcode Cloud?
I'm using SPM in my project and am trying to integrate Apple/swift-openapi-generator. My project is divided into several modules, for which I'm using SPM. To manage dependencies, I have a Package.swift file:
// swift-tools-version:5.8

import Foundation
import PackageDescription

let openAPIRuntime = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIRuntime", package: "swift-openapi-runtime")
let openAPIURLSession = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIURLSession", package: "swift-openapi-urlsession")
let openAPIGenerator = Target.PluginUsage.plugin(name: "OpenAPIGenerator", package: "swift-openapi-generator")

let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(
        name: "OpenAPIClient",
        dependencies: [openAPIRuntime, openAPIURLSession],
        plugins: [openAPIGenerator]
    ),
    //...
    ]

let package = Package(
    name: "Modules",
    platforms: [.iOS("16.0"), .macOS(.v11)],
    products: targets.filter { !$0.isTest }.map { .library(name: $0.name, targets: [$0.name]) },
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator", from: "0.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-runtime", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-urlsession", from: "1.0.0"),
        //...
    ],
    targets: targets
)

As demonstrated, I've added openAPIRuntime and openAPIURLSession products and the openAPIGenerator plugin to this file. As a result, I'm able to successfully build the project locally.
However Xcode cloud fails with the following error message:

“OpenAPIGenerator” is disabled.


How to fix this issue?

The workaround is to add a file named ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh to your project, with the following content:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipPackagePluginFingerprintValidatation -bool YES

Check here fore more infos about custom build scripts.

What does this script actually do?

Build tool plugins require you to trust them before first use. When you first build your project with the plugin in Xcode, you will be presented with a dialog asking you to trust and enable the plugin. As Xcode Cloud can't show you any dialog you just skipping the validation of plugins with this script.
